# Populate new dictionary from old dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<string, int>` where the string is a randomized collection of characters and the int is the ASCII sum of that string.

e.g.

```
    ["aaaaaaaaab", 971],
    ["aaaaaaaaba", 971],
    ["aaaaaaabaa", 971],
    ["aaaaaabaaa", 971]
```

I would like to make a new dictionary from the original where the new key is the value from the original, and the new value is the `List<string>` which would contain all the strings with the key as the ASCII sum.

e.g.

```
    [971, List<string>{ "aaaaaaaaab", "aaaaaaaaba", "aaaaaaabaa", "aaaaaabaaa"}]
```

How can I achieve this? I cannot wrap my head around the required steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use could [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) and [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.8)

The premise is :

1. *group by* the old `Value`
2. *project* to a new *dictionary* given the values of the `GroupBy`

   - which will be the *grouped* list of `KeyValuePair` from the original dictionary, that in-turn has the `key` selected out of it (`.Select(y => y.Key`)

**Example**

```
var newDict = old.GroupBy(x => x.Value)
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(y => y.Key)
                                                 .ToList());
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Enumerable.GroupBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8)

> Groups the elements of a sequence.

[Enumerable.ToDictionary Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.8)

> Creates a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` from an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I like most.

Answer (score 1):

Since values are not unique, you need to group by `Value` before converting to dictionary:

```
var inverse = original
    .GroupBy(p => p.Value)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(p => p.Key).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this without Linq, you could do the following:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in dict) {
    if(!dict2.ContainsKey(entry.Value)) {
        dict2[entry.Value] = new List<string>();
    }
    dict2[entry.Value].Add(entry.Key);
}
```

Assuming you have dict defined as `Dictionary<string, int> dict` and dict2 defined as `Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict2`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example for anyone that wants to "wrap their head around" how to do this, without LINQ.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string,int> origDict = new Dictionary<string,int>{{"tttt",1},{"fttt",1},{"fftt",2}};

        var vals = new int[origDict.Count];
        origDict.Values.CopyTo(vals,0);

        var keys = new string[origDict.Count];
        origDict.Keys.CopyTo(keys,0);

        Dictionary<int,List<string>> newDict = new Dictionary<int,List<string>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < vals.Length; i++){
            int val = vals[i];
            if(newDict.ContainsKey(val)){
                newDict[val].Add(keys[i]);
            }else{
                newDict[val] = new List<string>();
                newDict[val].Add(keys[i]);
            }
        }
        foreach(var key in newDict.Keys){
            Console.WriteLine(key);
            foreach(var val in newDict[key]){
                Console.WriteLine(val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
tttt
fttt
2
fftt
```